# Is there any way to give logged in condition in rspec? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my rspec file ->

```
  describe 'GET /users' do
    it 'test user list page' do
      get '/users'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
```

I maked login in my app, but I don't know how to define
'login' with 'before' in rspec file.
my login is using session, and I don't have to use specific user.
how can I check user logged in on rspec request test?
I want to test logged in user can access to /users url in rspec file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by mocking. The details depend on how your login status is determined, but suppose your application controller has a before_action like this:

```rb
# application_controller.rb

before_action :verify_login

# typically the checking is delegated
def verify_login
  Authorize.logged_in?(current_user, session)
end
```

Where the checking is executed in the `Authorize` service model.

Now in Rspec you just have to mock the response:

```rb
before do
  current_user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  session = Session.create
  expect(Authorize).to receive(:logged_in?).with(current_user, session).and_return(true)
end

it "should respond to logged-in user" do
  get '/users'
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)(
end
```

Comment: I don't use any gem, but can I use Authorize?

Comment: `Authorize` was just a hypothetical model that  I used in the example. You don't need a gem, you can make your own class to perform the authorization functions.

Comment: I'm sorry but where should I define hypothetical class? is this same as User model?

Comment: You are free to define a class as a container for functionality. It's just Ruby language. You can put the class in /lib, or /app/domain_models/ or even app/models. I just put a reference to it b/c it's commonly done this way.